# PC gaming freezes, upgrade recommended?

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade

Some computer games or software require higher computing performance, the smoothness of my current PC just doesn't satisfy me. Here are my specs:

```
OS: Windows 7
Windows Experience Points: Processing 6.4 Memory 7.2 Graphics 4.8 Gaming Graphics 5.8 Harddrive 5.9
HDD: 70% full 440GB
Processor: Intel Pentium CPU G620 @ 2.60GHz
Cache: L1 D:32KB L1 I: 32KB L2:256KB L3:3MB
Mainboard: Lenovo
Memory: 2GB + 4GB DDR3 2 Slots
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 1000(GT1)
```

I suspect the problems lays in the Intel HD Graphics, if so, what should I change to to increase my PC performance? Or is it a software problem or other hardware problem?

### Example Problems:

- Can't play a heavily modded Minecraft (talking about 40+ mods) (takes 98% CPU while playing if works)
- Starting Firefox would wait a minute and when it opens, it momentarily freezes a few times

Please comment if extra info is needed.

Comment: There is no upgrade based on your specifications that can help your CPU is the problem.  Your GPU also is almost 5+ years old so that also is a problem but not for minecraft.  Your CPU is also a problem which means an upgrade would cost more then a $250 computer.  Your motherboard won't support an upgrade to a different SandyBridge product

Comment: Agree with @Ramhound.  I also don't know Lenovo for really making gaming motherboards, like ROG or ASUS. You are looking at a total upgrade.  If you have cash to splash, go for a total gaming solution like Alienware. But be warned you are going to need lots of cash!!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly looking at your current spec, I dont think your motherboard supports that much RAM.

Second, if you upgrade now; you will need to upgrade complete system from CPU to motherboard.

Your RAM should work fine on new mobo.

I would recommend going for an AMD FX series CPU and mobo which will cost you less. If your budget is under USD $300. Go for AMD FX 6300 and FX compatible motherboard (ASUS M5A97) and AMD HD 6850.

Please note minecraft works well in 64bit os and 64bit JAVA.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! I'm a newbie to hardware in computing; I've checked the online manual of my motherboard and it said it can support 8Gb RAM. I think I will definitely buy a new PC sometime or later when I have time. :) (sorry, but I'm such a greedy person who wants more suggestions haha)

Comment: its always a good idea to look for specs and answers before buying any new hardware :) Good Luck.